# Mysql Index search menchizm - index on 3 columns while using only 2 in query

Tags: mysql

I have index on 3 columns in MySQL database (a, b, c).
Does it work when I query only for 2 or 1 of those? (`WHERE a = 1`).
Or only when using `WHERE a = 1 AND b = 1 AND c = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the index will work so long as you have conditions on the columns in the order that they are mentioned.  So, `a = 1` will use the index, but `b = 1` probably will not (unless MySQL decides that a scan of a covering index is faster than a scan of the table).

MySQL documentation explains this pretty well in the section on [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).